# How to makes repeated background request to server in android O and above

Tags: android, service, android-workmanager

I have an app doing request to the server every 30 seconds. I makes it using service. After changing the target version to the 26, service stop working in the background. Now I start service using ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startIntent) but this approach requires to show notification in the status bar. WorkManager did not help me, because it have a minimum period of 15 min. There is some way to make background requests every 30 sec without showing a notification?

Comment: Google added these restrictions so you won't do this.

Comment: It is very sad(

Comment: You can try with `JobScheduler`.

Comment: JobScheduler require API 21, but I have min version 16(

Comment: A little bit off-topic but is it really necessary to support down to SDK 16? Android below 21 is unable to handle TLS 1.1 handshakes so some urls aren't accessible at all anymore. For myself I also changed the min SDK of my app from 19 to 21, and got rid of a lot of extra work that way.

Comment: I know it. This is required by my client (

Answer (score 3):

You can use RxJava to do a task repeatedly.

```
Observable.timer(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).repeat()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(object : Observer<Long> {
                    override fun onComplete() {}

                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

                    override fun onNext(t: Long) {
                       //do your task
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}
                })
```

Comment: yep, but what will be if I kill the app?

Comment: You can have a disposable and dispose it off on onDestroy method of the Activity

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: u can use jobintentservice..... @PradeepPathak is it run on background??

Comment: To run the task on background, use Schedulers.io() or Schedulers.newThread() in observeOn, instead of mainThread. Or you can have another observer to run the task on different thread, and run that on onNext